# How to add drop down menu to widget in android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android

I'm using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Here's my tool bar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/scannerSettingsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/scannerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:textOn="SCAN"
        android:textOff="STOP"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here's my icons in the toolbar layout

[image]

I would like a drop down menu to appear when the user clicks on the `@id/scannerSettingsButton` which is the wrench styled icon boxed in with red farthest to the right.

Here is an example of a drop down menu

[image]

Any idea how to add a drop down menu to my `ImageButton`?

Thanks

Comment: Have u tried to add spinner

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it. It wasn't what I expected. I was hoping to choose an icon and be able to apply a drop down menu to it.

Comment: check the answer, might help you

Answer (score 2):

Create your menu.xml file like this

```
    <menu 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="menu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" >
    <menu>
         <item
            android:id="@+id/submenu1"
            android:title="sub_menu1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/submenu2"
            android:title="sub_menu2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/submenu3"
            android:title="sub_menu3" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Override onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar,menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Override onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.submenu1:
//add your method
                return true;

            case R.id.submenu2:
//add your method
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if using a menu inflater will work with the toolbar layout...

Comment: Give it a try me it doesn't work then we will try some thing else

Comment: use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Does this solution help you?